# jquery appending multiple elements to DOM loses sort order

Tags: jquery, html, dom, append

I have an object (returned from a json request) that has multiple records that I want to append to the DOM.  The object elements are in a specific order that needs to be maintained as I insert these elements into the DOM.

I want to insert them efficiently so I've setup this code block to add the elements to an object wrapper then insert the wrapper at one time rather than appending each object elements independently:

```
 var elmsToAppend = $();
 $.each( goFailureInfoRecords, function(i,e){

     elmsToAppend = elmsToAppend.add(
            $('<button/>', {
                'class': 'el-contents-center multiple-record',
                'html' : e.CreatedShort + &nbsp;Test#: ' + ( e.TestNum ? e.TestNum : 'None' ) + '&nbsp;' + e.CreatorID,
            })
    );
 });

$("<div/>").html( elmsToAppend );
```

The problem is that when `elmsToAppend` gets added to `<div>` with the `.html()` function the original order of the elements within `goFailureInfoRecords` gets mixed up.

How can I preserve the order of the elements within `goFailureInfoRecords` without iterating over each element and appending them to the DOM individually (which increases overhead)?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
posters have been asking to display what goFailureInfoRecords contains so here is the output:

```
Object
   FailRecords: Array[3]
   0: Object
       Created: "2013-06-04 10:00:37"
       CreatedLong: "Tue Jun 4, 2013 10:00 AM"
       CreatedShort: "06/04/13 10:00 AM"
       CreatorID: "152204"
       DefectID: null
       EventID: "1455"
       MfgRev: "03"
       Mode: "PRODUCTION"
       PartNumber: "3EM22617ACAF"
       Symptom: null
       TestNum: "4"
       __proto__: Object
   1: Object
       Created: "2013-06-03 21:34:54"
       CreatedLong: "Mon Jun 3, 2013 9:34 PM"
       CreatedShort: "06/03/13 9:34 PM"
       CreatorID: "76705"
       DefectID: null
       EventID: "1431"
       MfgRev: "03"
       Mode: "PRODUCTION"
       PartNumber: "3EM22617ACAF"
       Symptom: null
       TestNum: "10"
       __proto__: Object
   2: Object
       Created: "2013-05-30 18:22:06"
       CreatedLong: "Thu May 30, 2013 6:22 PM"
       CreatedShort: "05/30/13 6:22 PM"
       CreatorID: "76705"
       DefectID: null
       EventID: "1354"
       MfgRev: "03"
       Mode: "PRODUCTION"
       PartNumber: "3EM22617ACAF"
       Symptom: null
       TestNum: "10"
       __proto__: Object
   length: 3
```

The order in question is the order of FailRecords elements 0, 1, and 2

Comment: Order is never guaranteed in an object, so you can't rely on that.

Comment: You should add a property to goFailureInfoRecords objects which specify an order and then add elements to DOM according to this property value

Comment: @roasted could you provide an example?

Comment: @sadmicrowave could you provide how do you create your list of goFailureInfoRecords objects?

Comment: The problem isn't really the loop or the inserting into the DOM, that happens in order, but the order in goFailureInfoRecords is by no means guaranteed. You should be using an array if order is important, but you'll have to show us what goFailureInfoRecords contains ?

Comment: @roasted its an ajax call to a php program that does a mysqli query on a database and finishes the query with "ORDER BY a.Field1, a.Field2 DESC"

Comment: @adeneo - see my OP for an update including the output of goFailureInfoRecords

Comment: And if you use a for loop, is order preserved? goFailureInfoRecords[0], goFailureInfoRecords[1], etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing the $() with an array:

```
var elmsToAppend = new array();
$.each( goFailureInfoRecords, function(i,e){
     elmsToAppend = elmsToAppend.push(
        $('<button/>', {
            'class': 'el-contents-center multiple-record',
            'html' : e.CreatedShort + &nbsp;Test#: ' + ( e.TestNum ? e.TestNum : 'None' ) + '&nbsp;' + e.CreatorID,
        })
     );
});
$("<div/>").html( elmsToAppend );
```

The jsfiddle i used was [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/uFkTu/)

Comment: the order is lose in the $.each() loop so setting your array inside it will just returns the wrong order. The idea is not bad though

Comment: well, according to the description "FailRecords: Array[3]" (i'm assuming it is just an array), so it should keep order (http://jsfiddle.net/uFkTu/2/)

Comment: i saw, so why not use a for loop: for `(var i = 0, z = goFailureInfoRecords.length;i<z ;i++)`

Comment: I assume that is exactly what jQuery is doing (didn't check the source).

Comment: I like this solution because it is very close to my current methodology for inserting the elements.

Answer (score 3):

See if this works ?

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (key in goFailureInfoRecords) {
    var btn = document.createElement('button'),
          e = goFailureInfoRecords[key];

    btn.className = 'el-contents-center multiple-record';
    btn.innerHTML = e.CreatedShort +' &nbsp;Test#: ' + ( e.TestNum ? e.TestNum : 'None' ) + '&nbsp;' + e.CreatorID;

    frag.appendChild(btn);
}

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(frag);

$('#some_actual_DOM_element').html(div);
```